# ASP.NET MVC Web Deploy - MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion not being generated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using VS2013 Professional and I have 2 separate ASP.NET MVC projects, both created from scratch in VS2013 Pro.

Both are using Code First to manage the database and both have migrations enabled via "Enable-Migrations" in the Package Manager console. Some changes to the DB are required when the apps are installed on IIS. To do this I would like to use Code First Migrations to perform the DB updates.

The problem I'm having is when I come to publish each project into a "Web Deploy Package" and I check the "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)" checkbox, **I get slightly different results in the resulting ZIP package**.

The difference is that the web.config file on one project contains the additional `<add>` object for `_DatabasePublish` within `<connectionStrings>` and also the `"MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion'2"` databaseInitializer within the `<context>` as expected.

**However the other project doesn't contain either of these additional elements which means that the DB changes don't get made when deployed to IIS.**

I've compared the settings for both projects but can't seem to work out why there is a difference in the output. The only way I can get the failing project to output the required XML is to change the "Configuration" dropdown in the Publish wizard from "Debug" to "Release". That isn't ideal because I would like to leave the configuration as "Debug" in this case (I'm releasing to UAT and want to be able to easily debug issues). I realise I could simply add the debug parameter back in once I've deployed to IIS but would prefer to rely on VS to output the correct XML for me.

The app which is working as expected successfully outputs the correct XML whether the Configuration is "Debug" or "Release".

I guess I must be missing something so any pointers on what is restricting the correct XML in the failing project would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using web.config transformations? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx

Comment: I'm not using transformations. I would expect that by checking the "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)" checkbox, that the resulting web.config is automatically updated as detailed in the Summary section here: (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx) but it seems to be inconsistent for some reason which I can't work out.

Comment: Have you looked at each of the web.config files that are deployed to the servers. According to this article checking that box should modify the web.config file by adding the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion element to the web.config file.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: 2. Select Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start).

This option causes the deployment process to configure the deployed Web.config file to specify the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer. This initializer automatically updates the database to the latest version when the application accesses the database for the first time after deployment.

Comment: Hi Adrian. Sorry if I wasn't clear but that's exactly my problem, the checkbox isn't having any effect in some cases which is causing the DB to not be updated when I deploy.

Comment: Can you post your Settings.pubxml, Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config and web.config? Otherwise you can consider using web config transformations which will give you the result you are looking for.